# Calculate Percentage Change from to Last Date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to Calculate Percentage Change   to Last Date.

For example, the date chosen now is June 2023. I need to calculate the percentage change  of sales from dec 2021, to june 2023,

when the chosen date is May 2023, I need to calculate the percentage change  of sales from dec 2021 to May 2023 and e.t.c

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaGbx.png):

**sales it is  a measure  that is calculated depending on the selected date:**

```
sales = 
VAR sale = 
CALCULATE(
        SUM('sales'[sales]),
            FILTER(
                ALL('dates'[date_sale]),

                    'dates'[date_sale] >= MAX('dates'[start_period]) && 'dates'[date_sale] <= MAX('dates'[end_period]) 
                  )
        )
return sales
```

how i am calculating the percentage change:

```
% = 
VAR latestperiodbeg =
    CALCULATE (MAX('dates'[start_period]))
VAR latestperiodend=
    CALCULATE(MAX('dates'[end_period]))

VAR start_period= DATE(2021,01,01)
VAR end_period= DATE(2021,12,01)

VAR dec2021 =
    CALCULATE ( SUM('sales'[sales]), 'dates'[date_sale] >= star_period && 'dates'[date_sale] <= end_period 

VAR latest_date =
    CALCULATE ( SUM('sales'[sales]),'dates'[date_sale]>=latestperiodbeg && 'dates'[date_sale]<=latestperiodend)
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( latest_date, dec2021)
```

What i am expecting:

[What i am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJZ3h.png)

the dashboard above uses this measure:

```
max_date = IF(MAX(dates[date_sale])=DATE(2023,06,01),'Мeasures'[%],BLANK())
```

So, how can I dynamically change the date (2023,06,01) in above measure depending on the selected date value?

Comment: use SELECTEDVALUE('DImDate'[Date]) to return the value the user chooses, and use that in your measure instead of DATE(2023,06,01)

Comment: @Pieter  I tried to  used 
var md=SELECTEDVALUE('dates'[date_sale])
var a=IF(MAX('dates'[date_sale])=md,'Measures'[%],BLANK())   It doesnt work. Result is similar pic 1 in my post

Comment: If all you're doing is a simple date shift, and it's not working... do you have a Calendar dimension in your model? That would explain why it's hard.